# Backup text file using date string

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to append a date string to the file name to back up a text file
So I did:

```
cp "$infile" "$infile"_backup_ date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
```

But its not working, how can I append the output of "date" in a string?

```
user1@serv01:~/test_sh_append> date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
20171222_075003
user1@serv01:~/test_sh_append> echo date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
cp "$infile" "${infile}_backup_"$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
```

- `${infile}` - variable `$infile` interpolated within concatenated string
- `$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")` - command substitution, the output of which becomes the ending part of the resulting concatenated string (new *filename*)

---

If the `date` format specifier would contain whitespace(s) like `%Y%m%d %H%M%S` - wrap the entire concatenated sequence with double quotes `"${infile}_backup_$(date +"%Y%m%d %H%M%S")"`

Comment: Thank you! This works! can you explain the magic?

Comment: @user648026, yes, see the explanation

Comment: +1.  But...while this is safe enough with this `date` command using that format string, as a general rule it is better to wrap the entire string in double quotes.  e.g. `"${infile}_backup_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")"`.  This works correctly even though it looks like the double-quotes are nested, because the `$(date...)` is in a completely new/separate quoting context.  If the format contained any whitespace characters or other shell metacharacters then quoting it as I've mentioned would be **required**.

Comment: @cas, ok, added notation

Comment: You might want `cp -p` instead of plain `cp` to preserve the metadata such as timestamps and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I have done by below method

```
i=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`;  cp inputfile inputfile_$i
```

where i is variable which contains date command output